# Association analysis in Python - memory error on groupby

Tags: python-3.x, out-of-memory, market-basket-analysis

I am doing an association analysis in a problem like 'Market Basket' (find products that are sold together). I have a dataset of 12 months with 150Mb of data, approx 7mi registers (Invoices and the products, among other data). I think it doesn't worth going to Hadoop.. I'm following this tutorial (http://pbpython.com/market-basket-analysis.html), but I'm getting Memory Error in the df.unstack() part.

```
data = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for date in files:
    df = pd.read_csv('VND_%s.csv' % date,
                    sep=';',
                    skiprows=0,
                    names=names,
                    index_col=None)
    list_.append(df)
data = pd.concat(list_)

basket = (data.groupby(['INVOICE', 'MATERIAL'])['TOT_QUANTITY']
          .sum().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0))

def encode_units(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return 0
    if x >= 1:
        return 1

basket_sets = basket.applymap(encode_units)
frequent_itemsets = apriori(basket_sets, min_support=0.05, use_colnames=True)
rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="lift", min_threshold=1)

print(rules.head())
```

And if you find something that could be improved please tell me. I'd appreciate.